# How to add a new ATL COM class into an existed project via vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, com, atl

I am trying to add a new COM class into an existed project (this project is created by vc++ 6.0 and migrated to vs2010), when I clicked "add a simple COM object", but vs2010 pop up a dialog saying "Do you want to add ATL support to your project", if I have to choose "YES" to move on, but actually the project can be compiled successfully. I don't think I need to add ATL support.

Did anybody meet the same problem before or know how to add a new COM interface automatically or manually by vs2010 without "add ATL support"?

thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely do COM without ATL, but this is unlikely to be what you want because ATL is the best base for COM development (esp. if you want to be guided by Visual Studio wizards in COM object creation).

So yes, you need to add ATL support, and resolve compiler/linker issues that might be taking place, then add COM object classes to your project.